# TURN protocol : Permissions for remote users

Tags: sip, nat, sdp, stun

I am implementing TURN protocol for ICE. If the remote party sends its HOST,SERVER-REFLEXIVE and RELAYED-REFLEXIVE addresses in SDP ,should we create permissions to ALL(host,SERVER and RELAYED ) the remote candidates in the TURN server OR  just to RELAYED-REFLEXIVE address ?

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to set permissions for **all** known IP addresses of the remote host.  The usual connectivity with TURN will be with the SERVER-REFLEXIVE address of the remote host.

Comment: Thanks @selbie for the reply.

We will be using media relay through TURN servers in ICE only when both the devices are behind port-restricted NAT(most of the cases).

My question is :
1.Cant we NOT include TURN candidates in ICE ? If ICE without TURN candidates fail,we can just send a re-invite with Media relay address ?By this , we need not do Connectivity checks through relay candidates ,and thus the time taken for ICE(without TURN) will be less.
2. What is the standard Industry practice when it comes to ICE?

Thanks and regards,